# Please change background colour for code in quote

Tags: feature-request, design

Currently both quote have background colour `#F4F4F4` and code block `#F3F3F3`. On my monitor they are indistinguishable.

Making code background darker is bad for readability, so please make code block in quote lighter, for example `#FCFCFC`:

[image: Mockup]

Hopefuly, we will avoid edits [like this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26040), if this will be implemented.